# HP OfficeJet 6500 - Horizontal lines on scans/copies

Tags: printer, all-in-one

I'm having trouble with my HP OfficeJet 6500 all-in-one. I'm out of warranty, so there's little help from HP...

When I scan or copy something, using either the flatbed or the ADF, I get horizontal black lines randomly across the document. I've got the latest drivers and the latest updates.

I know it isn't a dirt issue on the screen -- the lines are in different places...sometimes it's just a few at the bottom, sometimes it is all over the screen.

I thought it might be a PC issue -- but it happens in standalone copy mode, too.

Any ideas?

Here are a couple of examples...

Tame example:
[image: Tame Example]

Really bad example:
[image: Bad example]

Comment: Sounds to me like a controller problem. I fear you may have to replace the machine.